# How to perform the multiplication rule for selecting two items without replacement?

Tags: sympy

I'm experimenting with sympy to reproduce an example where a box has three marbles:

- Red
- White
- Blue

Two marbles will be drawn at random without replacement.

*Q: What is the chance of drawing the Red marble and then the White marble?*

I have been able to calculate this using the multiplication rule by *hard-coding* P() instances wrapping the initial distribution before the first marble is selected and then the distribution before the second marble is selected:

```py
from sympy.stats import DiscreteUniform, density, P
from sympy import symbols, Eq

# Coloured marbles
R, W, B = symbols('R W B') 

# Select first marble without replacement
PFirstSelection  = P(Eq(DiscreteUniform('FirstSeletion',   (R, W, B)), R))

# Select second marble - Red is not longer available because it was selected without replacement
PSecondSelection = P(Eq(DiscreteUniform('SecondSelection', (W, B)   ), W)) 

print(PFirstSelection)
# 1/3

print(PSecondSelection)
# 1/2

# Multiplication rule
print(PFirstSelection * PSecondSelection)
# 1/6
```

Is there a better way that I can achieve this with sympy?

Comment: Someone has downvoted with no explanation why.  I have no idea how to improve this question without a comment.

Comment: I guess because it's having an immediate mathematical answer: # possibilies: 3!/1! or 3*2. Sympy, or even python are not required. Maybe for a more general problem that would be interesting.

Comment: @Soleil - thanks for the feedback.  If that's the case, maybe you could add your comment as an answer?  I.e. there doesn't appear to be a way to do this with sympy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you'd better to use combination functions.

DiscreteUniform seems not for changing elements after creation.

```
from sympy.functions.combinatorial.numbers import nC, nP

print(1 / nP(3, 2)) # 1/6
```

If you don't care about order,

```
print(nP(2, 2) / nP(3, 2)) # 1/3
```

---

Edited. (and also modified for python3)

For N of M things, you can simply do like below

```
from sympy.functions.combinatorial.numbers import nC, nP

def pickProb(candidates, picks, ordered=False):
    picks_num = len(picks)
    numerator = nP(picks_num, picks_num) if ordered else 1
    denominator = nP(len(candidates), picks_num)
    return numerator / denominator

print(pickProb('RWB', 'RW')) # 1/6
print(pickProb('RWBrwba', 'Ra')) # 1/42
print(pickProb('RWBrwba', 'RWa')) # 1/210
print(pickProb('RWBrwba', 'RWa', ordered=True)) # 1/35
```

And combination functions can also handle duplicates, like 'R', 'R', 'W', 'B'.

```
from operator import mul
from sympy.functions.combinatorial.numbers import nC, nP

def pickProb(candidates, picks):
    picks_num = len(picks)
    c_counts = {}
    for c in candidates:
        c_counts[c] = c_counts[c] + 1 if c in c_counts else 1
    p_counts = {}
    for p in picks:
        p_counts[p] = p_counts[p] + 1 if p in p_counts else 1
    combinations = reduce(mul, [nP(c_counts[x], p_counts[x]) for x in p_counts.keys()], 1)
    denominator = nP(len(candidates), picks_num) / combinations
    return 1 / denominator

print(pickProb('RWBra', 'RWa')) # 1/60
print(pickProb('RRRWa', 'RWa')) # 1/20
print(pickProb('RRRWa', 'RRa')) # 1/10
```

But `DiscreteUniform` cannot, because this case is not "uniform".

```
from sympy.stats import DiscreteUniform, density, P, Hypergeometric
from sympy import Symbol, Eq

deck = DiscreteUniform('M', 'RRWB')
print(density(deck).dict) # {W: 1/4, R: 1/4, B: 1/4}
print(P(Eq(deck, Symbol('R')))) # 1/4
```

Comment: Your answer is right, but in programming you want to write generic functions (ie., written once, usable many times); an you did the opposite by hardcoding the data of the problem. I believe Chris wanted to go to the opposite direction (ie., to a more generic code).

Comment: @Soleil Thanks! I'll improve my answer! And your answer seems great:)

Comment: Also, I believe Chris is writing in python 3, not 2 ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using correctly sympy, but you can improve your way to use python (eg., more generic, more functional, more generic, no hardcoding).

For instance:

```
from sympy.stats import DiscreteUniform, density, P
from sympy import symbols, Eq
from itertools import accumulate


def ToSet(value):
    return set(value.split(' '))


def ProbaOfPick(pickSet, fromSet, operationTag):
    return P(Eq(DiscreteUniform(operationTag, symbols(fromSet)), symbols(pickSet)))


def PickWithoutReplacement(allset, picklist, probaFunc):
    currentSet = allset
    probaSeq = []
    operationSeq = []
    for pick in picklist:
        operationTag = "picking: " + pick
        newP = probaFunc(pick, currentSet, operationTag)
        operationSeq.append(operationTag + " from " + str(currentSet))
        probaSeq.append(newP)
        currentSet -= set(pick)
    return (operationSeq, probaSeq)


allset = ToSet('R W B Y Ma G1 G2')
picks = 'R', 'W', 'G2'
operationSeq, probaSeq = PickWithoutReplacement(allset, picks, ProbaOfPick)

probas = list(accumulate(probaSeq, lambda a, b: a*b))

for op in operationSeq:
    print(op)
print(probas)
```

Also your can change uniform distribution to anything non-uniform.

EDIT: dependency injection (`ProbaOfPick` -> `probaFunc`) added.

This code is only a starter.

Result:

```
picking: R from {'G2', 'Ma', 'Y', 'B', 'R', 'G1', 'W'}
picking: W from {'G2', 'Ma', 'Y', 'B', 'G1', 'W'}
picking: G2 from {'G2', 'Ma', 'Y', 'B', 'G1'}
[1/7, 1/42, 1/210]
```

Next steps: allow to pick more than 1 each step, allow non uniform probability distribution, etc